# How do I profile a Python program with non explicit function calls?

Tags: python, profiling, netcdf

I am trying to profile a program using kcachegrind. My program uses netCDF4-python, which reads files using the syntax

data = var[:]

I am having trouble getting any information for the function call tree below this step. I've had a look round to see what could be causing this and because the syntax isn't an explicit function call I cannot see what functions this calls or the breakdown of how long the called functions take.

I've thought about using line_profiler in the netcdf4-python library but I think because of how it is installed I would not be able to add the @profile decorator into the library.

Is there a way to get kcachegrind to enter the non explicit function call? Or is there a better tool for this task?

Comment: That's equivalent to `var.__getitem__(slice(None))`

Comment: Is [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771) of any help?

Comment: One of the other problems here for profiling is that that function is implemented in Pyrex (pre-cursor to Cython), and thus is compiled to C--I doubt line_profiler can handle that.